# How can I get Skype to work in Ubuntu 13.04 64-bit?

Tags: 64-bit, 13.04, skype

It worked before, but I reinstalled Ubuntu, and now I can't get it to run when I install it. It simply doesn't run.

UPDATE: I found the solution [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/04/7-things-to-do-after-installing-ubuntu.html).